# asp.net loads to the first tab when i make action in another tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have three tabs like this:

[image]

When I press on the last table, there is a code behind executing to get data from database. I have done all of that.

#### my problem

in the last tab there is a button, when I press it. it loads the whole page and then returns to the first tab open.

#### what I want

when I pressing that button in the last tab, I want to get the data and present it, whit out making the page goes to the first tab.

#### i am sure it is something about post back but i don't know anything about it

#### Edit

this is my code in c#

```
protected void BookingForDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//do something in database and fill the table
}
```

#### Edit2

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// go to database and get data to fill it in the first tab

}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code behind class code?

Comment: use an update panel in the last tab or post back using ajax and display the response. are they jquery tabs?

Comment: @ChristosPaisios I did

Comment: @Adween could you give example using just c# without jquery? or if you want use jquery but let it fire a c# code

Comment: @user2226785 thanks. I need also to see the code for the Page Load event. I suspect that there is the problem.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios I did

Comment: hm, do you use if(!Page.IsPostBack) in the Page_Load event?

Comment: @user2226785 Read about UpdatePanel and its usage. There a full postback happening in your condition, which is reloading entire page of yours. Using update panel the page will do partial postback. Means part of the page gets refreshed and your view will not alter completly.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios no I don't

Comment: @Bharadwaj could you give me an example in an answer please?

Comment: Try to include all your code in the Page_Load event in if(!Page.IsPostBack){ }

Comment: @ChristosPaisios `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` will work with `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios no I don't want to make all my code in the page load, because it is a heavy code in the database. and the customer rarely open the third tap.

Comment: @user2226785 there is an answer already. You can read from that link.

Comment: @ChristosPaisios there are many cases for postback, as i Know, so is there any case to tell the asp that if this postback happened because the button on the third tab please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a post that should get you started with update panels

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx

Here is the minimum you need on the page with it writing out the datetime. so you can see it works

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Other content in the panel. -->
        <%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Refresh Panel" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```